# Flutter/Dart Sort List only where bool true is

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart

I'd like to achieve that only Tourneys where the bool `isActive` is true to be shown and sorted in the order where the Date of the Toruney is the nearest of the current Date.

at the `List<NewPokerTourneyClass> avail` I get three Tourneys, which is correct, but when I want to sort the `List<NewPokerTourneyClass> avail` the Tourneys do not get sorted. With the commented out sort function it sorts all Tourneys which is not the thing that I want.

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: _pokerTourneyProvider.tourney!
              .where((element) => element.isActive == true)
              .length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            List<NewPokerTourneyClass> avail = _pokerTourneyProvider.tourney!
                .where((element) => element.isActive == true)
                .toList();
            avail.sort((a, b) {
              final one = a.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
              final two = b.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
              return one!.compareTo(two!);
            });

            // _pokerTourneyProvider.tourney!.sort((one, two) {
            //   final oneMilli = one.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
            //   final twoMilli = two.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
            //   return oneMilli!.compareTo(twoMilli!);
            // });
```

Comment: try to move 
`List<NewPokerTourneyClass> avail = _pokerTourneyProvider.tourney!
                .where((element) => element.isActive == true)
                .toList();
            avail.sort((a, b) {
              final one = a.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
              final two = b.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
              return one!.compareTo(two!);
            });`
to outside of `itembuilder` and check if it is not sorted again, for instance in init state or something

Answer (score 0):

just separate your sorted function and update the **_pokerTourneyProvider.tourney** list.

```
List<NewPokerTourneyClass> getTurneySortedList(bool order) {
List<NewPokerTourneyClass> availList = _pokerTourneyProvider.tourney!
            .where((element) => element.isActive == true)
            .toList();;
```

order is a boolean type value. if ascending pass order = true, if descending pass order = false.

```
 if (order) {
      availList .sort((a, b) => a.createdAt!.compareTo(b.createdAt!));
    } else {
      availList .sort((a, b) => b.createdAt!.compareTo(a.createdAt!));
    }

    return availList ;
  }
```

Comment: First of all, ThankYou for your answer but sadly adding ```getTurneySortedList(true)```
to the itemBuilder is not sorting the list like
```_pokerTourneyProvider.tourney!.sort((one, two) {
            final oneMilli = one.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
            final twoMilli = two.dateTime?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
            return oneMilli!.compareTo(twoMilli!);
            });``` even changing your code to millisecondsSinceEpoch is not doing the trick